# Unexpected token o in JSON: How to fix?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to save member data as JSON, but it is not working. I'm using [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/) framework.

I have searched Stack Overflow and many other sites, but I can't find a solution.

Here's the code snippet:

```
const user = message.guild.members.get(message.mentions.users.first().id);
const file = (user.id + ".json");
const content = {
    "name": user.username,
    "isFlagged": false,
    "punishments": 1,
    "id": user.id,
    "discrim": user.discriminator
};
var B = content.toString();
fs.writeFileIfNotExist(file, B, function(err, existed) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log('file created sucessfuly!')
    }
});
let points = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./' + user.id + '.json'));
points.isFlagged = false;
points.punishments = points.punishments + 1;
```

Comment: `content.toString()` is probably returning the string `"[object Object]"`. Not what you want. Maybe try replacing that line with `var B = JSON.stringify(content)` instead.

Comment: It is unclear as to what you mean. Can you clarify? Are you asking you need help in developing a `json` file to store your data in?

Answer (score 0):

As, CRice notes, calling `Object.prototype.toString` on an object created from a literal and not shadowing `toString` with an implementation returning a JSON formatted string, will return the string `"[object Object"]` which is not what you want.

This is demonstrated by the following snippet:

```js
const content = {
  name: 'John Smith',
  isFlagged: false,
  punishments: 1,
  id: 5,
  discrim: Symbol()
};
const b = content.toString();

console.log(b);
```

So first, change your code as follows

```js
const content = {
  name: 'John Smith',
  isFlagged: false,
  punishments: 1,
  id: 5,
  discrim: Symbol()
};
const b = JSON.stringify(content);

console.log(b);
```

Lastly, consider rewriting your program to cleanly and consistently leverage asynchronous IO and improve your naming patterns to follow established JavaScript conventions.

```
const promisify = require('util.promisify');
const fs = require('fs');

const exists = promisify(fs.exists);
const writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);

const user = message.guild.members.get(message.mentions.users.first().id);
const file = `${user.id}.json`;
const content = {
    name: user.username,
    isFlagged: false,
    punishments: 1,
    id: user.id,
    discrim: user.discriminator
};
const b = JSON.stringify(content);

(async function () {
    try {
        await writeFileIfNotExist(file, b);
        console.log('file created sucessfuly!')
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
    const json = await readFile(`./${user.id}.json`);
    const user = JSON.parse(json);
    user.isFlagged = false;
    user.punishments = user.punishments + 1;
}());

async function writeFileIfNotExists(fileName, data) {
    if (await exists(fileName)) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        await writeFile(fileName, data);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): The "original" argument must be of type function

Comment: @Braguetta `fs.writeFileIfNotExist` is not a real Node.js API but you used it in your question so I just borrowed the concept. That is why you are getting that error.